# xlcalert not working in XLL SDK example

Tags: c++, xll

I am new to XLL development.  I downloaded 2010 XLL SDK and was able to build the example in VisualC++ 2012.  When I load the xll in Excel2010, I am seeing the popup with "thank you ..." message and I am seeing all the functions exported from the example in Excel, so it seems everything is loaded successfully.

But, the xlcalert does not work in most of the functions. I am only seeing popup dialog from `xlcalert` in `xlAutoAdd` and `xlAutoRemove`.  I even modified `EvaluateExample()` function to just do:

```
Excel12f(xlcAlert, 0, 2, TempStr12(L"Finished EvaluateExample"), TempInt12(2));
```

When I run the function, I don't see popup.  What am I missing? I can't seem to find much references to xlcalert.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to XLL development, do yourself a favor and use http://xll.codeplex.com.

Your example would be `ExcelX(xlcAlert, OPERX(_T("Finished EvaluateExample")), OPERX(12))`

The code will work with either the old or new SDK.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone looking for the answer for this question - one can find it here:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6951ef0a-a66a-489a-b0da-9516667bffa9/xlcalert-in-xll-example

Long story short:

> You also see 1 in the cell if you use it as a function for cell. However if you run it as a macro via Application.Run "xlGetNameExample" you will see the dialog. I think your issue is similar like it. Please try it. Let's see whether you can see the prompt.